# Scan API with authorization headers

Tags: owasp, zap

I have a case where some of my endpoints are with different authorization.
For example, request1 return response with value1, which has to be turned into Base64 and then to be used in request2 as a header and so on.
Therefore, I need to grab values from the response and turn them into Base64.

Which is the best way to do that - via the Zap UI or just create a separate script file and use it when run zap-api-scan.py?

I'd also appreciate any examples of similar scripts.

Answer (score 1):

ZAP is highly scriptable, so thats the way to go. You can create a test the scripts in the UI and then use them in automation. You'll want to use an httpsender script - there are a load of examples here: https://github.com/zaproxy/community-scripts/tree/master/httpsender

Comment: Thanks, Simon! I'll look at it.